# Flatten a List of Lists and create a default item if the list is empty with lambda syntax

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of lists I got from a GroupJoin. I know to flatten it I can use SelectMany, which works fine. My problem is that some of the lists are empty. In this case I want to default them to a single new item when SelectMany is called.

Is there anyway to do this simply in SelectMany or do I need to loop through my list of lists first and insert the default record into any empty collection?

Comment: Use `DefaultIfEmpty`

Comment: Is there anyway to get that behavior in the SelectMany without having another method call? Its not a requirement but curiosity

Comment: `SelectMany(x => x.List.DefaultIfEmpty())` What's the problem with the method call, you **have** to do something anyway, right?

Comment: Yea... I dont know why I didnt even think of calling it in the predicate. I think it might be time to call it for the day. Thank you for the help